# How to make the first row of each group as sum of other rows in the same group in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
    A   B   
0  67   1    
1  78   1    
2  53   1    
3  44   1    
4  84   1    
5   2   2    
6  63   2    
7  13   2    
8  56   2    
9  24   2
```

My goal is to:

1) group column A based on column B

2) make the first row of each formed group as a result of groupby() a sum of all other rows of this group. In this case, the value in the first row will be overwritten by the sum.

My desired output would be:

```
    A   B   
0  259  1    
1  78   1   
2  53   1   
3  44   1   
4  84   1    
5  156  2   
6  63   2    
7  13   2    
8  56   2    
9  24   2
```

So, the first row of group 1 (grouped based on column B), we have 259 in column A because the values, except the very first row, for group 1 are 78+53+44+84 = 259

For group 2, the first row of group 2 is 156 because 63+13+56+24 = 156

I spent days trying to figure out how to do this and I finally surrender, here's hoping someone in this great community will help.

Comment: is your data already sorted on 'B'?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way:

```
grp = df.groupby('B')
```

---

Method 1 (similar to @Kent deleted answer):

```
s=grp['A'].transform('sum').sub(df['A'])
idx=grp.head(1).index
df.loc[idx,'A']=s
```

---

Method 2:

```
v= [g.iloc[1:].groupby('B')['A'].sum().iat[0] for _,g in grp]
idx = grp.head(1).index
df.loc[idx,'A'] = v
```

---

```
print(df)
```

---

```
     A  B
0  259  1
1   78  1
2   53  1
3   44  1
4   84  1
5  156  2
6   63  2
7   13  2
8   56  2
9   24  2
```